# Xamarin Page Navigation is not working in Task Continuation

Tags: c#, xamarin, async-await, task

```
 public class CreateAccountViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private INavigation navigation;
    public CreateAccountViewModel(INavigation navigation)
    {
        this.navigation = navigation;
    }
```

Navigation Object is Injected via Constructor

```
protected async Task ExecuteCreateAccountCommand()
    {
        if (validateDetails())
        {
            try
            {
                IsLoading = true;
                await SvcHelper.SvcHelper.CreateUserAsync(new Services.Models.LoginInfo
                  {
                      LoginId = Email,
                      LoginPassword = Password,
                      UserId = 0,
                      UserHandle = Cellno
                  }).ContinueWith(x =>
                  {

                      IsLoading = false;
                      (Forms.Context as Activity).RunOnUiThread(async () =>
                          {

                                await navigation.PushModalAsync(new MyPage());
                          }
                       );
                  });
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("###Error### : " + exc.Message + exc.StackTrace);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // details not valid
            //await DisplayAlert ("Alert", "Email Address not valid", "OK");
            return;
        }
        await navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
}
```

navigation is not working in ContinueWith , I just want to navigate to MyPage() after I CreateUserAsync has been completed . How can I do that . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting an exception?

Comment: @StephenCleary : No I am not getting any exception . Also while debugging , I got to know MyPage() object is successfully created and returned.

Comment: Why are you using `ContinueWith` instead of executing the code inline after the first `await`?

Comment: I doubt that `PopModalAsync` is run before `PushModalAsync` because of nested async..